# Rollbacks showing GUID key in summary instead of Revision number on mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, rollbacks

[image: Cropped look at a rollback on profile]

So today I looked at someone's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6375113/bugs?tab=activity&sort=revisions) on their profile while being on my phone (The mobile site view).

Instead of saying "Rollback to Revision X" it displays "Rollback to [*GUID*]". I can't say for how long this existed, all I know is it happens.

Using Chrome on Android 5.0.2

Comment: cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289456/hash-key-in-the-mobile-web-for-rollback-revision

Comment: The key is the revision GUID.